# What is the accepted typography for latin phrases?

Tags: latin, typography

In an academic article, i'm using a lot of latin phrases both abbreviated (i.e., e.g., etc.) and spelt out (de facto, in situ...). I know that in certain languages, the most commonly accepted form is to write the latin phrases in italics.

What is the standard for English ? Should I set all the latin phrases in italics? Only the spelt out forms?

Comment: Searching online I found this:  _According to The Chicago Manual of Style, you don’t need italics for foreign language words that your readers will find familiar. De facto comes from Latin, but English speakers have used it for centuries._ You certainly don't need to italicise abbreviations such as 'e.g.', which are well established in English.

Comment: @KateBunting, your comment is the answer; is there any reason for not posting it as such?

Comment: @KateBunting — I would respectfully second jsw29’s point, and ask why you repeatedly ignore the injunction in the comment box, only to use comments to ask for clarifications or suggest improvements in the question.

Comment: @jsw29 Mea culpa - or should it be _mea culpa_ ? I think I 've been criticised for posting answers without detailed references, so I often hesitate between the two.

Comment: @David Perhaps you have a suggestion as to how to try to (a) help the person asking the question and (b) forestall 'answers',  when the question is too basic or unresearched for ELU, or almost certainly already answered in another thread?

Comment: @jsw29 I'd have thought that the existence of a duplicate, found easily by a regular contributor by doing a little basic research (on-site search for 'Latin' + 'italics'), is a good reason not to give an 'answer'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — This and other people can be helped: 1. By answering their questions in answers. The voting and comment system on SE is devised to allow people to judge answers in this way. 2.When the questions are too basic, by directing them to SE English Language Learners. 3. When the questions are unresearched, by pointing out the requirements to do so in the Help. But this site is not a Charity Shop. There is no obligation on users to respond to inappropriate questions, and the Help advises to only answer questions worth answering. Commenters may mean well, but actually damage the list.

Comment: @David As Kate's answer is provided elsewhere on ELU, non-answering and close-voting would improve the site.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting that the best course of action to take on this site is not always clear. But of course, that's a subject to discuss on EL&U Meta, so I'll stop here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching online I found this:

According to The Chicago Manual of Style, you don’t need italics for foreign language words that your readers will find familiar. De facto comes from Latin, but English speakers have used it for centuries.

You certainly don't need to italicise abbreviations such as 'e.g.', which are well established in English.